# Queryable.Select using selector expression with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, iqueryable, func

I have defined a selector expression that looks like this:

```
private Expression<Func<myTable, MyCustomModel>> selectorExpression = m => new MyCustomModel
{
    ID = m.id,
    Name = m.name,
    Score = 10
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
IQueryable<DebtorModel> query = (from myTable in context.myTables
                                    where myTable.id == 4
                                    select myTable).Select(selectorExpression);
```

What I want to do is to pass the score as parameter so I made something like this:

```
private Expression<Func<myTable, int, MyCustomModel>> selectorExpressionV2 = (m, score) => new MyCustomModel
{
    ID = m.id,
    Name = m.name,
    Score = score
}
```

Can I apply selectorExpressionV2 to the query above? I tried this:

```
IQueryable<DebtorModel> query = (from myTable in context.myTables
                                    where myTable.id == 4
                                    select new {myTable, score = 10}).Select(selectorExpressionV2);
```

But it's not working. I get an error, something like 
the type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage try specifying the type arguments...

I don't realize how I should write this... or if it is possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
select new {myTable, score = 10}
```

You create an annonymous type and so, selectorExpression should be `Expression<Func<MyAnnonymousType, MyCustomModel>>` but you can't do this since it is an annonymous type.

You should create a new class to hold the values of myClass and score as Ben Robinson stated in his comment or if score is a constant in the whole linq statement you could do this:

```
private Expression<Func<MyClass, MyCustomModel>> GetSelectorExpression(int score) {
    return m => new MyCustomModel
    {
        ID = m.id,
        Name = m.name,
        Score = score
    }
}
```

Then when using it:

```
var selectorExpression = GetSelectorExpression(10);
IQueryable<DebtorModel> query = (from myTable in context.myTables
                                    where myTable.id == 4
                                    select new myTable).Select(selectorExpression);
```